# How to iterate over an NSArrayController contents in swift?

Tags: swift, nsarraycontroller, for-in-loop, xcode7

I have an array controller which stores managed objects of entity 'Student', I am trying to iterate over its content using below code:

```
for (index, element) in downloadingFilesArrayController.arrangedObjects{
    // want to do some useful things on element
}
```

for some reasons it is showing compilation error:

```
'Type AnyObject does not conform to protocol SequenceType'
```

Any ideas on how can fix it?

Comment: Why is arrangedObjects of type AnyObject? Should it not be an array?

Comment: Probably because `arrangedObjects` returns a proxy, which emulates NSArray, but is not actually one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for element in downloadingFilesArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [AnyObject] {
    // want to do some useful things on element
}
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful for me in guiding me towards correct path, I made it working by making few modifications, I have updated your answer as well with the code which worked for me.